# Syntax - Assigning a variable then putting it in while loop doesn't work. Why?

Tags: python

I'm wondering why this won't work:

```
n = 10
x = 1
while x < n:
    x += 1
    n += n * (x - 1)
print n
```

I've already assigned n = 10, placing it in the while loop should be like placing a 10 there. Running it in Terminal acts like I've placed a raw_input() there.

This works:

```
n = 10
x = 1
while x < 10:
    x += 1
    n += n * (x - 1)
print n
```

It looks the same to me...

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't. You're modifying `n` in the first example. Resulting in different behavior of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understand it after doing more loops of similar type. The reason is that this creates an infinite loop because in:

```
n = 10
x = 1
while x < n:
    x += 1
    n += n * (x - 1)
print n
```

The n increases along with x:

```
x += 1
n += n * (x - 1)
```

So x never catches up with n and causes an infinite loop.

This works because the 10 never increases and x can catch up with it.

```
n = 10
x = 1
while x < 10:
    x += 1
    n += n * (x - 1)
print n
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, `n`, your limit, is increasing (`n += n * (x - 1)`) and you have an infinite loop. In the second one the limit is constant (`10`) so it terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Because, in the while loop, for each iteration, you also update `n`

```
while x < n:
    x += 1
    n += n * (x - 1)
```

So, after the first few iterations, n is no longer 10, and it keeps increasing.

Comment: That explains it. N keeps getting bigger, x can't pass it. But what would I do if I wanted to place a raw_input variable inside the while statement? Thanks.

Comment: @LoiHuynh Look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-raw_input-examples/), this is how you get raw input, just use another variable `raw`, for example, to store it.